# ORA-12154 with Visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, oracle, visual-studio, devops

I've got massive problem with connecting to an Oracle data base.
Whatever I do, when I start my application, I get a 500 error with

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

in system log details.

My colleagues from work have an identical setup (identical web.configs and solution data) and never has this problem occurred for them.

Anonymized snippet from web.config :

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="config" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.com)(PORT = 9999))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = name.com)))" />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionConfig" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="Pooling=false;Data Source=config;User Id=user;Password=password" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Summing up - as you can see I don't use TNS_ADMIN with TNSNAMES.ora file (because I directly provide the Data Source).
I have Java installed and the Oracle DB client works normally.
Other guys use the same web.config so password and other data is correct.

Please share any ideas!

**EDIT:**

process monitor shows that tnsnames.ora was readed, so i created one in source directory (ensure it was readed at startups) added

```
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
            (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.com)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA = 
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = name.com))
    )
```

and still same error

Comment: Do you have environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` specified? I think it takes precedence over the web.config file (and may point to an empty file/directory)

Comment: Try to remove spaces from the description line. For example `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.230)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=TICKET)))`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
I'm 99% sure that when I'm using ODP.NET and provide dataSource in <oracle.manageddataaccess.client> tag - I'm not using TNS_ADMIN
anyway i do have that environment variable for user and system, have access to file - it don't contain my datasource, but other guys use same tnsnames with same web.config and don't have problem :(

Comment: @DmitryDemin tried that and it didn't help :(

Comment: If you are just 99% sure the download the Process Monitor from [Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and check which file is actually loaded (at first).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i have updated post

Comment: Maybe you can share your database connection code?  I have also had odd errors when the same code works on another users' computer - try a full clean, delete the bin and obj folders and then build